# creating in c++ a vector of templates whose type is unknown (void templates)

Tags: c++, templates

I have a C++ template class that contains a method pointer and a class pointer, and who has single method, `call`, that calls the method pointer on the class pointer.

This template is called `Method< C >`, C being the class of the class and method pointers.

I want to create an array (`std::vector`) of this template, but I want this vector to be able to contain different classes of this template. My final goal is to go through this vector and call the `call` method of each of the elements, even if they have different classes.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not store `template`s in `vector`, only `objects` that have `types`. And `template` become `type` when it is instantiated.

So, you can't do exactly what you want.

I recommend you use `function` and `bind`. See an example:

```
struct A
{
    void call()
    {
        std::cout << "hello";
    }

};  

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::function<void()>> v;
    v.push_back(std::bind(&A::call, A()));
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        (*it)();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It does exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods all have the same signature (with respect to the input parameters and return type) then you could wrap them in `std::function` objects and store those in the vector.  Either way, it sounds like you'll need to wrap your class in some sort of polymorphic type (or derive them from a common, non-templated base -- but then you'll have reinvented `std::function`.)

The bottom line here is that `std::vector` cannot be made to store heterogeneous types.